# Create Camera Driver MFT and use it in Windows 8 Metro Style app?

Tags: c#, driver, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to create Windows 8 Metro app to provide different effects on camera stream. For this i found out to write Driver MFT for camera. But i have no idea how to write this and use it in my application. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSDN page describing how to write one is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There is also an sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).